# DataGridView binding not working

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, datagridview

I am working on a winforms project and i have this following code in the Form_Load method. But it doesnt work. Can anyone help me?

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Sella.Properties.Settings.Database1ConnectionString1"].ConnectionString);
// A SqlCommand object is used to execute the SQL commands.
SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From CustCalls", conn);
// A SqlDataAdapter uses the SqlCommand object to fill a DataSet.
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(scmd);
// Create and Fill a new DataSet.
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
sda.Fill(ds);

dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
```

Comment: Can you define "it doesn't work"?  Nothing showing up in the grid, or is there an error.  If there is an error, please edit it into your question.

Comment: Is the DataBindingComplete event firing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try sourcing directly to the table in the dataset:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(scmd, conn);

dataTable dt = new DataTable();

sda.Fill(dt);

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: Its better to describe your answer a little